# background image that moves when you scroll down the page

Tags: html, css

I keep seeing websites with a background image that subtly moves when you scroll down.  This is a really nice effect but I'm not sure how to do this?  I'm am experienced with html, css and jquery but this is something I haven't done before!

I have a simple jsfiddle below but I need some help please!

Many thanks,

http://jsfiddle.net/def2y2yt/

**Code snippet - more available using the jsfiddle link**

```
.background {
    background-image: url(example.pjg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 600px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Like TylerH said, it's called Parallax. You can see an example [here.](http://jsfiddle.net/apederson/z93R7/)

Using JavaScript:

```
var velocity = 0.5;

function update(){ 
var pos = $(window).scrollTop(); 
$('.container').each(function() { 
    var $element = $(this);
    // subtract some from the height b/c of the padding
    var height = $element.height()-18;
    $(this).css('backgroundPosition', '50% ' + Math.round((height - pos) * velocity) +  'px'); 
   }); 
   };

 $(window).bind('scroll', update);
```

Comment: thanks to everyone for all the comments, that's really great.  I'll go and play with it now..

Comment: @TylerH I wish you would have shown this to me yesterday. I believe I can take some from this and make what I was trying to do work.  (and learn more JS basics to include each and this) Thanks ;)

Comment: Continuation: This also circumvents the problems associated with background-attachment: fixed and is indeed true parallax vs faking it with background-attachment: fixed as I was taught

Comment: This is great and so close to what I need ...Is it possible to do this only affecting to vertical value? I have 4 panels, each with different background-images and just want them to animate as they come into view. The image horizontal position is alternated between left/right/left/right so this affects both values?

Comment: Have been pulling my hair out for an entire evening trying to find a solution to make exactly this. This works very well out of the box. Thanks !

Answer (score 21):

Or you could use this simple CSS property which I made a blog post about:
http://nathanpeixoto.fr/blog/article8/web-un-one-page-presque-sans-javascript
(French only, sorry).

Let's say this is your HTML:

```
<div class="background_container">

</div>
<style>
.background_container{
  background-image: url("XXX");
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed; /* <= This one */
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 3):

The best library for that is [Stellarjs](http://markdalgleish.com/projects/stellar.js/)

Take a look at the example here

http://markdalgleish.com/projects/stellar.js/demos/backgrounds.html