# Background image still moves upon placing background-attachment as fixed, and z-index as -1

Tags: html, css

My background image still moves a few millimeter up while scrolling up and a few millimeter down while scrolling down. And I've looked up some possible methods to fixing this issue but all I got was to place z-index as -1; and that I did, but still moves while scrolling.
Here is a short clip of what it looks like.

https://mittsspp.000webhostapp.com/20201221023609.mp4

Please what can I do to make this background image standstill while scrolling possibly in all browsers.

Here's a snippet of the code

```
  body {
    background-image:  url(https://mittsspp.000webhostapp.com/Pictures/panoramic-3267048.jpg);
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    background-color: rgba(0,60,105);
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: Make your code runnable here or put a jsfiddle in your post like this poster did. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25369487/background-image-that-moves-when-you-scroll-down-the-page

Comment: I just posted a snippet already

Comment: @GloriaWhite You've shared some CSS, but no HTML to go along with it. Do you only have the `<body>` tag and no actual content inside it?

Comment: It does. The video explained it better I guess

Comment: This explains it better.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33327127/dummy-image-placeholder-for-webpage

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
background-attachment: fixed;
background-position: center;
```

Comment: I did all of that but it still moves just like in the video.